# How to set when text will wrap?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a left-floated image with text (in a `<p>` element) on its right side, with no text wrapping around the image by using `display: flow-root` on the paragraph element. What I would like is to be able to start wrapping text around the image when a set number of lines, say three, have overflowed beneath the image. Is there any way to do this?
Edit: These two images are a clarification of what I'm trying to do.

From this:
[image: no text wrap layout]

To this, when another line ends up beneath the image (because of screen resize or similar event):
[image: text wrap layout]

In other words, this should make the text wrap *only* when the screen size is such that the text is flowing below the image by three lines or more.

My existing code (for image and text in container):

```css
.listing-img{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
 display: flow-root;
}
.listing-content{
 display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<section class="listing">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300?text=About+the+Farr+Homestead" class="listing-img" />
 <p class="listing-content">
 A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a    healthy
 orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the  ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall grass. This benefits beneficial insects
 and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed
 about twice a year to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once
 shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
  mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in
 the orchard.
 </p>
</section>
```

[The result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhjPa.png)

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can get images at placeholder.com

Comment: so you want the image to take specific width and height and the text on the right!

Comment: @cloned answer is correct. You can't wrap the text around the image if they aren't on the same context, so you have to change your html structure and move the img inside the p tag. After, if you want the text to start wrapping exactly when 3 lines have passed below the image, then you should have to give a margin-bottom to the img of exactly 3 times the line-height of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Why not move the image inside the paragraph and control the distance between image and paragraph via margin?

```css
.listing-img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="listing">
  
  <p class="listing-content">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300?text=About+the+Farr+Homestead" class="listing-img" />
    A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a healthy orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall
    grass. This benefits beneficial insects and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed about twice a year
    to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
    mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in the orchard.
    
        A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a healthy orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall
    grass. This benefits beneficial insects and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed about twice a year
    to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
    mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in the orchard.
    
        A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a healthy orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall
    grass. This benefits beneficial insects and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed about twice a year
    to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
    mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in the orchard.
    
        A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a healthy orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall
    grass. This benefits beneficial insects and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed about twice a year
    to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
    mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in the orchard.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem I had with this was that it leaves a space between the bottom of the image and the text. I tried bottom margin on the image outside the paragraph as well, but the same problem shows up there as well.

Comment: Now I'm confused, I thought you wanted a space between the bottom of the image and the text. Can you post an image on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the main post with images showing the transition I was hoping for.

Comment: This won't be possible with CSS, you might use JS for this. You can check the height of the image and the height of the text, and if the height is bigger than X you add a class to the text and this class then enables the floating.

Comment: I'm okay with using JS for this. If there's a JQuery solution out there may I have an example? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may set paragraph to display inline and add margin-bottom to image to create space.

However, if you have long words which will not fit on line such word and text after will be shown after image.

So tweaking word-break css property may be useful (break-word seems to me not working in firefox and break-all looks a bit ugly). Also you may add soft hyphen `&shy;` if necessary.

```css
.listing-img{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
 display: flow-root;
 margin-bottom:3em;
}
.listing-content{
 /* display: flow-root; */
 display:inline;
 word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<section class="listing">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300?text=About+the+Farr+Homestead" class="listing-img" />
 <p class="listing-content">
 A key feature of the apple orchard management structure in the Farr Orchard will be maintaining a    healthy
 orchard understory. Apple trees grow naturally in hedgerows along the edge of forests, where the  ground is usually covered with wildflowers and tall grass. This benefits beneficial insects
 and pollinators by providing habitat and keeps the soil fertile for the tree, which in turn supports better fruit size and cropping when applied to an orchard. Tree rows will usually be mowed
 about twice a year to maintain the same perennial wildflower domination - once
 shortly after blossom, around July; and again before harvest begins, in mid to late September. In addition to the mulching effect caused be cutting the grass at these key points, wood chip
  mulch and gravel will keep the root system of the trees healthy and free from excessive weed pressure, while not harming surrounding plants. This will promote genetic diversity in
 the orchard.
 </p>
</section>
```